# Javascript Dictionary Value coming out as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a normal dictionary in my react App that looks like this:

```
{firstName: "Jackson", lastName: "Metivier", post: "another another post post", postId: 4, time: "Fri, 24 Jul 2020 22:59:25 GMT", …}
```

and I'm trying to add a key and value pair to it which i've only been able to do doing this:

```
post['key'] = value
```

and I go console.log the dictionary after and it looks like this:

```
{firstName: "Jackson", lastName: "Metivier", picture: "blob:http://localhost:3000/30bc97e2-32f6-401f-8a80-a9cf9cec78c9", post: "Another post", postId: 3, time: "Fri, 24 Jul 2020 22:58:31 GMT",userId: 1}
```

so the key value pair is clearly added to the dictionary... but then when I try and call the value of 'picture' it comes out undefined.

also, when I try and call the picture value from my render statement, it is also undefined.

I have no idea what is happening, any insight into this matter would be greatly appreciated...

Here's my full code on the component I'm working on with the areas in question marked.

```
const Blog = () => {
const history = useHistory();
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ 'data': '' })
const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState({ 'data': [] })
const [postPicture, setPostPicture] = useState('')
const [getPosts, setGetPosts] = useState(false)
const [newPostPicture,setNewPostPicture] = useState('')


const getPicture = (user_data) => {
    user_data.data.map((post) => {
        fetch(`/profile_picture/${post.userId}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Origin': 'localhost:3000',
                'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
                'Acces-Control-Request-Headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'JSON'
                }
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.blob().then(data => 
                    post['picture'] = URL.createObjectURL(data) // WHERE I'M ADDING THE VALUE
            ))
    })
    setUserPosts(user_data)
 }

const getUserPosts = () => {

    fetch('/blog', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Origin': 'localhost:3000',
            'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
            'Acces-Control-Request-Headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'JSON'
            }
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json()
            .then(data => {
                getPicture(data)
            }))

}

useEffect(() => {
    getUserPosts()
}, []);

if (getPosts) {
    getUserPosts()
    console.log('new posts!')
    setGetPosts(false)
}


userPosts.data.map((post) => {
    console.log(post) // WHERE I'M SUCCESSFULLY CONSOLE LOGGING THE DICTIONARY AND ALSO GET UNDEFINED WHEN I CALL THE PICTURE KEY
})
return (
    <div className='profile'>
    <MakePost 
    setGetPosts = {setGetPosts}

    />
    WHERE I ALSO GET UNDEFINED WHEN I CALL THE PICTURE KEY
    </div>
)
}
 export default Blog
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue stems from your use of the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function—more specifically, your use of the asynchronous [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) function therein. Since the promise returned by `fetch` is asynchronous, it's likely you're calling `setUserPosts` with the outdated `user_data` before any of the in-place modifications have a chance to occur upon Promise fulfillment.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to wait for all of your fetches to complete and the corresponding assignments to occur *before* you call `setUserPosts`. Luckily, this is fairly simple to achieve by passing an `async` function to `map` and using `Promise.all` to await completion.

Also, although it's not directly connected to your issue: the purpose of `Array.map` is to produce a *new* array based on the application of some function to the elements of an existing one, not to iterate through elements of an array for the purpose of modifying them in place (since `post` is being passed by reference). In general, in React, it's best to avoid the sort of in-place modification you're performing; instead, operations like `map` allow you to generate modified copies for later use. To make copies of objects (like `user_data` and `post`), either use the spread operator (e.g., `let newObj = { ...obj, newProp: newVal}`) or `Object.assign` (e.g., `let newObj = Object.assign({}, obj); newObj.newProp = newVal`). Doing this is more in line with React's principles and will probably avoid headaches down the road.

To see what I mean, here's a simplified version of what you're doing (using `setTimeout` to simulate your async `fetch` call and `console.log` in place of `setUserData`). I've written two approaches that illustrate how to use an asynchronous function with the `await` keyword in the `map` call to ensure that values are loaded before you do something with them (one using the spread operator, one using `Object.assign`):

```js
// Dummy data
const user_data = {data: [
    {firstName: "Jackson", lastName: "Metivier", post: "another another post post", postId: 4, time: "Fri, 24 Jul 2020 22:59:25 GMT"},
  {firstName: "Jackson", lastName: "Metivier", post: "another post", postId: 5, time: "Fri, 25 Jul 2020 00:00:28 GMT"},
]}

console.log('Current approach (not working)')
user_data.data.map(post => {
    asyncFunc().then(data => {
    post['picture'] = 'my_picture'
  })
})
doSomething(user_data)

// Using spread operator
Promise.all(user_data.data.map(async post =>
    ({...post, picture: await asyncFunc()})
)).then(user_data_data => {
  console.log('Using spread operator')
    doSomething({...user_data, data: user_data_data})
})

// Using Object.assign
const user_data_copy = Object.assign({}, user_data)
Promise.all(user_data.data.map(async post => {
    const new_post = Object.assign({}, post)
  new_post['picture'] = await asyncFunc()
  return new_post
})).then(user_data_data => {
  console.log('Using Object.assign')
    user_data_copy.data = user_data_data
  doSomething(user_data_copy)
})

// Dummy functions
function asyncFunc () {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => { res('data') }, 1000);
  })
}
function doSomething (data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

So, in the case of your code, your function would become something like the following (using the spread operator example):

```js
const getPicture = (user_data) => {
    Promise.all(user_data.data.map(async (post) => {
        const res = await fetch(`/profile_picture/${post.userId}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Origin': 'localhost:3000',
                'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
                'Acces-Control-Request-Headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'JSON'
                }
            }
        })
        const data = await res.blob()
        return {...post, picture: URL.createObjectURL(data)}
    })).then((user_data_data) => {
        setUserPosts({...user_data, data: user_data_data})
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  What a detailed thought out answer.  We need more people like you in the world.  <3